# Disabling the form element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form like this: -

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="banner_ad_post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p>
                  <label for="banner_name"><font color="#FF0000"> * </font>Banner Name: </label>
                  <input type="text" name="banner_name" id="banner_name" value="" maxlength="100" required="required"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label for="Banner_website_url"><font color="#FF0000"> * </font>Banner website Url: </label>
                  <input type="url" name="banner_site_url" id="banner_site_url" value="" maxlength="100" required="required"/>
                </p>

                <p>
                  <label for="banner_image_url">Banner Image Url: </label>
                  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="" accept="image" placeholder="Browse from hard disk" onchange="img_path()"/> &nbsp;
                   <font color="#FF0000"> OR</font> &nbsp;
                  <input type="url" name="banner_image_url" id="banner_image_url" value="" maxlength="100" placeholder="Enter the url from website." onchange="validate()"/> &nbsp; 


                </p>
                <p>
                <label for="submit"> </label>
                  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                </p>
              </form>
```

And the JavaScript code like : -

```
<script>

    function validate()
    {
    var banner_name=document.getElementById("banner_name");
    var banner_site_url=document.getElementById("banner_site_url");
    var banner_file=document.getElementById("file");
    var banner_image_url=document.getElementById("banner_image_url");
    //var x=banner_file.value;
    //var y=banner_image_url.value;
    if((banner_file.value=true) && (banner_image_url.value=true))
        {
        alert("Please choose only one field either url or image uploading.");
        document.getElementById("form").reset();

        }
    }

    function img_path()
    {
    var file_path=document.getElementById('file').value;
    if(file_path.match(".jpeg$")==".jpeg" || file_path.match(".gif$")==".gif" || file_path.match(".GIF$")==".GIF" || file_path.match(".JPEG$")  ==".JPEG" || file_path.match(".JPG$")==".JPG" ||file_path.match(".jpg$")==".jpg" || file_path.match(".png$")==".png" || file_path.match(".PNG$")==".PNG")
    {
      return true;
    }
   else
   {
   alert("Upload  .jpg/.gif/png  file olny");
   document.getElementById("form").reset();
   return false;
   }

}
</script>
```

Now, the problem is that, whenever I am trying to enter the only image url in the form. It generates an alert message stating " (Please choose only one field either url or image uploading) ". But according to my definition the message should have to be displayed only when both the filed banner_image_url and file are set true.

Any help will be appreciated...
Thanx in advance.

Comment: There are probably more problems, but the first thing that pops up for me is that `banner_file.value=true` is an assignment, not a comparison. You need == instead.

Comment: You're using assignment (`=`) when you should use equality operator(`==`) : `if((banner_file.value=true) && (banner_image_url.value=true))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this:

```
banner_file.value=true
```

sets the value of `banner_file.value`, and returns `true`, **unconditionally**.

This is not what you want, since you want to check the existing value of `banner_file.value`.

On the other hand, doing this:

```
banner_file.value==true
```

returns `true` only if the value of `banner_file.value` evaluates to `true`. This *is* what you want to do.

Try it with the following changes:

```
if((banner_file.value) && (banner_image_url.value))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use == instead of =

```
if((banner_file.value==true) && (banner_image_url.value==true))
```

Comment: hey Ben! it is still not working. Now the problem is even more complex.The alert message is not popping at all even after providing both the fields.

Comment: +1, but you could also add an explanation of why `==true` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if((banner_file.value=true) && (banner_image_url.value=true))
```

should be:

```
if((banner_file.value == true) && (banner_image_url.value == true))
```

because, in your code you are setting the variable to true instead of checking if it is true. But if you want as little code as possible you could write:

```
if(banner_file.value && banner_image_url.value)
```

Explicitly testing for `== true` is redundant - but it can make the code more readable for some. Just thought I'd mention it in case you found the last example to be cleaner :)

Comment: Others beat me to it I see :)

Comment: Is it really boolean true, though?

Comment: @WolfgangStengel Nope, of course not. Sorry. Fixed it now. I've gotten a little too used to using === automatically I see :)